# File System Watcher has a user determined path?

Tags: c#, path, runtime, filesystemwatcher

How do you get the File System watcher to watch a path selected at run time e.g. the user can enter C:\Users\User\Desktop\

I have tried using a text box and a button which on click sets the path

```
    fileWatcher.Path = Convert.ToString(txtFileWatcherPath);
```

This builds and runs but any path entered crashes the program (once the button is clicked)

Please note at this early stage am not concerned with error handling.

Comment: Include stacktrace of your exception, please.

Comment: If `txtFileWatcherPath` is a textbox control, you should be doing this instead: `fileWatcher.Path = txtFileWatcherPath.Text;`

Comment: I just want to take a second and point how useful "Hungarian notation" has been here. Almost everyone reading the code snippet has immediately divined that `txtFileWatcherPath` must be a textbox control, given the `txt` prefix.

Comment: Perhaps you might also consider using a FolderBrowserDialog instead of asking users to input paths. But the answer is identified by several folks below.

Comment: @Bueller: Presumably there's a button next to the textbox control that, when clicked on, opens a FolderBrowserDialog. It probably has an ellipsis as a caption (`...`). At least, that's how it *should* be designed; that's the standard Windows convention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if `txtFileWatcherPath` is a textbox, then use `txtFileWatcherPath.Text` instead of `Convert.ToString`

Comment: Cheers, forgot about the .Text. Been a few weeks since I have worked on C#